# Best way to insert data into a Bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I would like to know if there are any preferred way to insert data into a bigquery table?

I am inserting new rows to a BQ table at the end of a Cloud Composer DAG. I've used a custom operator based on the [`BigQueryOperator`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html?highlight=bigquery%20operators#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator) as the following:

```
INSERT INTO `<project>.<dataset>.<table> (col1,col2,col3)
VALUES
(ccc,ccc,ddd),
(...,...,...)
```

The values added to the table can be up to 500 rows (...,...,...) but it is generally around 10-100 rows.

Is there a recommended/better way to do this? I don't know if it worth passing by GCS since the "file" containing all the rows won't be big.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `INSERT` has a cost (size of data inserted), vs a load job via GCS which will be free.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Traditionally `INSERT` wasn't an option, but it's now here for convenience.

If the cost is negligible, and this is the most convenient option - go for it.